# Strongloop loopback ios swift sdk override repository error

Tags: ios, swift, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am usign strongloop's loopback ios sdk.Running XCode 6.3.

**Objective:** To create an instance of **custom** LBUser model class from **custom** LBUserRepository.

**Code:**

```
class UserProfileRepository : LBUserRepository
{
    override class func repository() -> UserProfileRepository {
        let repo = UserProfileRepository(className: "userprofiles")
        return repo
    }
}
```

**Error:**
I get an error: `Cannot override 'repository' which has been marked unavailable`
Why is this error coming ? is it a swift error in newer version?

**References:**
Apart from [official documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/iOS+SDK), I am doing it the same way as it is depicted here : 
[Strongloop iOS User Creation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351811/strongloop-ios-user-creation-error)
and also I have even seen exact code in the test cases of obj c to swift converted code: https://github.com/Black-Tobacco/loopback-sdk-ios/tree/swift

Comment: Also you might want to check out my example on github: https://github.com/kgoedecke/loopback-swift-user-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
class ClientRepository:LBUserRepository {
    override init!(className name: String!) {
         super.init(className: "Clients")
    }
}
```